# Android: how do I access resources without a context from within the layout editor?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

Many Android components require the `Context` object. The community has many workarounds to this problem from passing the context, to dependency injection, to creating a custom application object.

**However, I've yet to find a suitable work-around that plays nice with the ADT layout editor!**

I can't use the typical "subclass the application object" approach because my application object is never instantiated within the layout editor; the layout editor instantiates a mock version instead. (`MockActivity` and `BridgeContext`) Most of the other approaches suffer from variations of this same limitation.

I have a version of my code that works like a champ by passing the Context, but as one might expect passing the context is ugly, it introduces design coupling I don't want, yadda yadda [insert usual Android issues here]. I'd rather avoid passing the context if at all possible.

The best idea I have is to create a custom widget for the sole purpose of setting a static context variable by using `View.getContext()` to grab the mock context. This will obviously work, but it's awfully hackish and I have two fears: 1) This adds unnecessary load to the layout inflater for something that I only need at design time. 2) I don't trust the operating system to reliably instantiate the widget and set the context before some other component needs to read it.

Is there a better approach?

I don't care if the design-time implementation is slow or memory hungry as long as it has no impact on the final run-time.

I'm not at liberty to switch development environments. Whatever the solution is, it *must* work with Eclipse.

Comment: Seems like a lot of thought and effort to merely assist with visual layout design.

Comment: Yeah, typically I'd agree but I've been asked for a large number of heavily themed layouts (>200 layouts counting fragments and adapters), so the time investment is worth it. The preview that lets me see a dozen handsets at once saves sooooo much time over side-loading a desk full of phones, at least to flesh-out the basics.